# Python dict is working similar to oderedDict?

Tags: python

In new version of python are dicts are working similar to orderedDicts?, can you provide me with reference.

Comment: Yes, the built-in `dict` type is ordered as of Python 3.7 ([release notes](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html)).

Comment: I cannot find about dict in the link you provided.

Comment: It's near the beginning, under "Python data model improvements": "the insertion-order preservation nature of dict objects has been declared to be an official part of the Python language spec."

Comment: Oh found it, Thank you @sj95126.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are dictionaries ordered in Python 3.6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, built-in dict is working like ordered dict from Python3.7
[image]

Thanks to @sj95126.

https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html